# Bomb lab assembly explanation

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

I am doing the bomb lab, and I guessed correctly that this is a Fibonnaci sequence (0 1 1 2 3 5). I am having trouble understanding the following lines: 8048d11-8048d1a

```
08048ce6 <phase_2>:
 8048ce6:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048ce7:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048ce9:       56                      push   %esi
 8048cea:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048ceb:       83 ec 30                sub    $0x30,%esp
 8048cee:       8d 45 e0                lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
 8048cf1:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048cf5:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048cf8:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048cfb:       e8 ca 04 00 00          call   80491ca <read_six_numbers>
 8048d00:       83 7d e0 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)
 8048d04:       75 06                   jne    8048d0c <phase_2+0x26>
 8048d06:       83 7d e4 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x1c(%ebp)
 8048d0a:       74 05                   je     8048d11 <phase_2+0x2b>
 8048d0c:       e8 77 04 00 00          call   8049188 <explode_bomb>
 8048d11:       8d 5d e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%ebx
 8048d14:       8d 75 f8                lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esi
 8048d17:       8b 43 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
 8048d1a:       03 43 f8                add    -0x8(%ebx),%eax
 8048d1d:       39 03                   cmp    %eax,(%ebx)
 8048d1f:       74 05                   je     8048d26 <phase_2+0x40>
 8048d21:       e8 62 04 00 00          call   8049188 <explode_bomb>
 8048d26:       83 c3 04                add    $0x4,%ebx
 8048d29:       39 f3                   cmp    %esi,%ebx
 8048d2b:       75 ea                   jne    8048d17 <phase_2+0x31>
 8048d2d:       83 c4 30                add    $0x30,%esp
 8048d30:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048d31:       5e                      pop    %esi
 8048d32:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048d33:       c3                      ret
```

I know that it keeps a tmp variable storing previous element, and add it up and compare with next one at 8048d1d. How does it do that exactly (though lea, mov and add)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically doing:

```c
int array[6];             // at ebp-0x20
int *ebx = &array[2];     // lea    -0x18(%ebp),%ebx
int *esi = &array[6];     // lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esi
do {
    int eax = *(ebx - 1); // mov    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
    eax += *(ebx - 2);    // add    -0x8(%ebx),%eax
    if (eax != *ebx)      // cmp    %eax,(%ebx)
        explode_bomb();
    ebx++;                // add    $0x4,%ebx
} while (ebx != esi);
```

Remember that C pointer arithmetic automatically scales by item size, but assembly is always in bytes. `ebx` is the pointer to the current element, the code sums up the previous two and checks for equality. `esi` is a pointer to the end of the array, that's used to exit the loop.